# Rx Kotlin: map function can't infer return type

Tags: android, reactivex, rx-kotlin

In an app that connects to bluetooth devices, I am using the following function using RxKotlin:

```
private fun startBluetoothPair(device: BluetoothDevice) {
    Observable.just(device)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map {
            var uuid: UUID = BLUETOOTH_UUID
            var socket = it.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
            socket.connect()
            return socket
        }
        .subscribe {
            // Do something with the BluetoothSocket
        }
}
```

This function should simply connect with the bluetoothdevice on the background and then do something with the socket (in the mainthread again). However, the `map` can't handle the `return socket` part, telling me there is a `Type mismatch`, it found a `BluetoothSocket` where it required a `Unit`.

What is going wrong here? I thought a map should be able to infer the return type.

Comment: Have you tried `return@scan` instead of `return`?

Comment: @Rehan: Thank you, that works! (Or at least, it doesn't complain anymore, can't test right now) But to me, `scan` looks like pure magic.. What does this do? Care to elaborate?

Comment: It is used to avoid ambiguities and return values in nested functions like your case above. I have seen android studio suggesting it more since I updated kotlin plugin last week. You can read more details [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) and [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax) :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your map function replace the statement

```
return socket
```

with

```
return@map socket
```

Because **return** statement is normally used to return values for top-level functions. For lambda expressions and inline (nested) functions, use returns at labels i.e. **return@{method_name}**. You can also leave last line just to **`socket`** in the case, and the compiler will handle it for you assuming the last line as return value for the inline function. But for better readability, I will definitely prefer  qualified return syntax. You can read more details in kotlin documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) and [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax)

Comment: Thank you buddy <3

Comment: Thank you! I was going mad trying to get Kotlin map to do what I need it to do. Why not do like other languages have already been doing?

Answer (score 2):

Just simply skip using the `return` keyword in this case! The last statement will be the return expression:

```
.map {
  val uuid: UUID = BLUETOOTH_UUID
  val socket = it.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)
  socket.connect()
  socket
}
```

It's recommended to avoid using labeled expressions like `return@map`, because of the maintainability and less complexity.

It's also a good practice using `val` instead of `var` for these variables since you don't reassign them.